# is this manifold diffeomorphic to the klein bottle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ given for the equations

$$x_1+x_2x_3x_4 = 0$$

$$x_2 + \sin(x_3x_4)^2 = 0$$

is this $2$-dimensional manifold diffeomorphic to the klein bottle?.
I first tried to see if it is orientable, but  I do not even know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manifold is not compact, so cannot be the Klein bottle. $(0,0,c,0) \in M$ for all $c$, hence it's not bounded (and thus not compact by Heine-Borel).

Comment: Thanks, I had to use another property of the klein bottle that I had not considered.